# How to solve invalid value encountered in double_scalars in mayavi with numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, visualization, mayavi

Here I got this error can you please guide me how to rectify this error, in my program I took x,y,z values in my csv file 
  RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  nx = (x - scale_min) / (scale_max - scale_min)

my code is given below:

```
class Visualization(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        # x = np.linspace(0,10,50)
        # y = np.linspace(0,15,50)
        # z = np.linspace(0,8,50)

        mycsv = csv.reader(open("./Tunnel.saf.csv"))
        for row in mycsv:
           x = float(row[0])
           y = float(row[1])
           z = float(row[2])

        X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

        s = np.cos(X) + np.sin(Y) + Z**0.5
        b1 = np.percentile(s, 20)
        b2 = np.percentile(s, 80)

        s = pipeline.volume(pipeline.scalar_field(s), vmin=b1, vmax=b2)
            #s = surf(x, y, f, colormap="Oranges")
            #s = outline()
        s = axes()
                #s = orientation_axes()
        #cs = contour_surf(x, y, f, contour_z=0)

        #self.scene.mlab.mesh(r[0],r[1],r[2], scalars=Y_lm.real, colormap="cool")

    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True # We need this to resize with the parent widget
                )
```

Comment: The csv reader module does not convert data types. It simply returns strings. You need to convert your row[i] to floats or ints (depending on your input) before calling np.cos.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but i changed the type of x,y,z values i got this error

Comment: Can you run your code in debug mode and see which function is causing the trouble ? It's hard to help with anything using a RuntimeWarning (which, by its very nature, is a Warning and not an error : it shouldn't prevent the script from running)